# How To Invert (Upside Down) Text In NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsstring, uitextview, core-text

How could I invert text in an NSString variable in iOS7?  (I want to display the text upside down).
Note: there are many solutions where the UILabel or UITextView is flipped upside down but this is not what I want.

Currently I can do the following in a category which reverses the string:

```
+ (NSString *)stringByReversingString:(NSString *)str
{
char cString[150];
char revString[150];
NSString *retval;
[str getCString:cString
      maxLength:[str lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] + 1
       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(cString); i++) {
    revString[i] = cString[strlen(cString) - (i + 1)];
}
revString[strlen(cString)] = '\0';
retval = [NSString stringWithCString:revString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

return retval;
}
```

But how would I turn the text upside down too?

Comment: ˙uʍop-ǝpısdn sı ɹoʇıuoɯ ɹnoʎ uǝɥʇ sıɥʇ pɐǝɹ uɐɔ noʎ ɟI

Comment: @MartinR that's it.  But how to do it programmatically? :D

Answer (score 4):

You *cannot* display a string upside-down with a pure string transformation, you have
to flip the view that contains the string.

There are *some* Unicode characters that are upside-down versions of "normal" letters,
such as

```
Ⅎ - TURNED CAPITAL F (U+2132)
```

but not for all characters.
You could only *mimick* the flipping by using a table like http://www.fileformat.info/convert/text/upside-down-map.htm:

```
uʍop-ǝpısdn sı ɹoʇıuoɯ ɹnoʎ uǝɥʇ sıɥʇ pɐǝɹ uɐɔ noʎ ɟI
```

(created using http://www.fileformat.info/convert/text/upside-down.htm)

But note that some letters have only a very rough upside-down approximation,
such as

```
K --> ⋊ - RIGHT NORMAL FACTOR SEMIDIRECT PRODUCT (U+22CA)
```

and many characters have nothing at all. So this suited for some fun display,
but not for a production app. Better flip the view.

Comment: Ok. If I go the flipping the uitextview and then the text is copied to clipboard is it copied as inverted or copied as normal way up?

Comment: @motionpotion: Normal way up. There is no way (that I know of) to mark a string as "upside-down".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to draw a string like this, subclass `NSLayoutManager` and override `-drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:atPoint:`, where you set the current context text matrix with `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1))` before sending `-showCGGlyphs:positions:count:font:matrix:attributes:inContext:`.
A quick sample that override `-drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:atPoint:` to draw text "upside-down", but don't take care of differents attributes like underline, strikethoughs …

```
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // setup text objects
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:[@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." stringByReversingString]];

    MyLayoutManager *textLayout = [[MyLayoutManager alloc] init];

    [textStorage addLayoutManager:textLayout];

    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];

    [textLayout addTextContainer:textContainer];
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height-20)
                                               textContainer:textContainer];
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
}
@end

@implementation MyLayoutManager
- (void)drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:(NSRange)glyphsToShow atPoint:(CGPoint)origin
{
    NSUInteger i;
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    NSRange lineRange;

    for (i = glyphsToShow.location; i < NSMaxRange(glyphsToShow); i = NSMaxRange(lineRange))
    {
        CGRect lineRect = [self lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:i effectiveRange:&lineRange];

        NSRange characterRange = [self characterRangeForGlyphRange:lineRange actualGlyphRange:NULL];

        /* This sample don't take care of different font attributes (size, etc ..) for the each lines */
        UIFont *font = [[self.textStorage attributesAtIndex:characterRange.location effectiveRange:NULL] objectForKey:NSFontAttributeName];
        UIColor *color = [[self.textStorage attributesAtIndex:characterRange.location effectiveRange:NULL] objectForKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];

        CGGlyph *glyphs = malloc(sizeof(CGGlyph) * lineRange.length);
        CGSize *advances = malloc(sizeof(CGSize) * lineRange.length);

        [self getGlyphsInRange:lineRange glyphs:glyphs properties:NULL characterIndexes:NULL bidiLevels:NULL];

         CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs((CTFontRef)font, kCTFontHorizontalOrientation, glyphs, advances, lineRange.length);

        [color set];

        CGFontRef cgfont = CTFontCopyGraphicsFont((CTFontRef)font, NULL);

        // setup CGContextRef to draw text "upside-down"
        CGAffineTransform textMatrix = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
        CGContextSetFont(ctx, cgfont);
        CGContextSetFontSize(ctx, [font pointSize]);
        CGContextSetTextMatrix(ctx, textMatrix);

        CGPoint position = lineRect.origin;
        position.x += origin.x;
        position.y += origin.y;

        int j;

        /* if you want the text to be right align, like the 'Lorem ipsum dolor' screenshot */
#if 1
        position.x += lineRect.size.width;
#else
        /* if you want the text to be left align */
        for (j = 0; j < characterRange.length; j++)
        {
            position.x += advances[j].width;
        }
#endif

        for (j = characterRange.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            [self showCGGlyphs:&glyphs[j] positions:&position count:1 font:font matrix:textMatrix attributes:nil inContext:ctx];
            position.x -= advances[j].width;
        }

        CGFontRelease(cgfont);

        free(glyphs);
        free(advances);
    }
}
@end
```

[image: text "upside-down" left aligned]
[image: text "upside-down" right aligned]

Comment: Hi, this is a mixture of CoreText and TextKit? And the letters are _truely_ upside-down (am asking because it seems like we are doing it just by sending the flipped context to the method)? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig Yes it's use both CoreText and TextKit, and yes letter are truly upside-down, this simply set Font and TextMatrix to the current `CGContextRef`. But this is really just a quick sample to show how we can do this kind of things, it doesn't do all what `-drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:atPoint:` should do and may be optimized.

Comment: May be optimized meaning that there is some performance issue here? Would you mind citing what might need to be optimized? Would it be OK for you to update it with a slightly more "complete" version, if it is not too much to ask? Thank you.

Comment: @Unheilig There is no noticed problem of performance, because this code was never used in a true application and because it was not demonstrated that it is a bottleneck. I just mean that the example was fast written by using CoreText, and that you can surely polish it and may make it better, nothing more. I edited the code, by removing an allocation memory for every line and the creation of the `CTFontRef` (I forgot that `CTFontRef` is toll-free bridged with `UIFont`), but without any guarantee of real improvement of the performances, because I don't have profiled all of this.